# Regular expression for finding exact given character set followed by another character set

Tags: javascript, regex, css-selectors

I have written a RegEx to replace,

```
#aa with #abcd 
.aa with .abcd
#aa> with #abcd>
#aa{ with #abcd{
#aa+ with #abcd+
#aa { with #abcd {
#aa{ with #abcd{
```

But

`#aaa{` should not replace with `#abcd{`

I am using below regex in javascript,

```
"test#aaa{".replace(/(#|.)aa(\s|\+|\.|>|,|{)/g, "$1abcd$2")
```

Ideally my use case is, Replacing `CSS ID/CLASS` in cssfileConents with `new ID/CLASS`

```
var cssContent = "test#aaa{";
var exp = "(#|.)" + oldIdValue + "(\\s|\\+|\\.|>|,|{)";
var regEx = new RegExp(exp, "g");
cssContent.replace(regEx, "$1" + newvalue + "$2");
```

Forgive my formatting :)

Comment: what are the possibilites other that aa you can get? i mean is  it always going to be 2 letters line bb cc dd ee etc or it may change ?

Comment: Would it be possible to see the actual CSScontent and the required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var repl = string.replace(/(#|.)\baa\b(\s|\+|\.|>|,|{)/g, "$1abcd$2");
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, \b is what I was looking for, "test#aaa{".replace(/(#|.)\baa\b(\s|\+|\.|>|,|{)/g, "$1abcd$2"). Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
"test#aaa{".replace(/([#.])aa(?![a-zA-Z])/g, "$1abcd");
```

Inside the character class `[]` a `.` means to only dot character. But outside `[]` a `.` means to any non whitespace character(which you are using right now).

`(?![a-zA-Z])` is negative lookahead. It is checking that the next character is not between `a` to `z` regardless the case.

Comment: `"test#aab{"` will not be replaced by `"test#abcdb{"`

Comment: @aelor That's why I mentioned about character from `a` to `z` in my answer. Which OP can change. Please read answer before making any comment.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex

```
([^a])aa([^a])
```

try in your console

```
var res = "test#aa{".replace(/([^a])aa([^a])/g, "$1abcd$2");
console.log(res);
```

demo here:

http://regex101.com/r/sO0cE2

Comment: But aa can be anything. Ideally it will from a variable,
var cssContent = "test#aaa{";
var exp = "(#|.)" + oldIdValue + "(\\s|\\+|\\.|>|,|{)";
var regEx = new RegExp(exp, "g");
cssContent.replace(regEx, "$1" + newvalue + "$2");

Comment: @aelor your regex fails with `baab`

Comment: @Darshan can you add more examples ?

Comment: @SabujHassan how can you say that ? its giving o/p as `test#babcdb{` which i guess is right ?

Comment: @aelor I meant `"baab".replace(...`

Comment: @SabujHassan it will give `babcdb` so what is wrong ?